# How to skip the Viewmodel in a database (ASP MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get;set; }
    public string userName { get;set; }
    public string userPassword { get;set; }
    public string userEmail { get;set; }
}
```

and an example viewmodel:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string userPassword { get; set; }
    public string userEmail { get; set; }
}
```

and a create action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(UserViewModel u)
{
    //user.ID = u.ID;
    user.userEmail = u.userEmail;
    user.userName = u.userName;
    user.userPassword = u.userPassword;

    dbContext.users.Add(user);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    return View();
}
```

So now I want to add only my model to the database but if I create a View then Visual Studio keeps adding this to the context:

```
   public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ProjectManagement.ViewModels.UserViewModel> UserViewModels { get; set; }
```

..which creates an additional empty table in the database. Why is that? What I should do if I want to separat model and ViewModel with validation, data, etc.?

Comment: In action `user` varible is undefined? You are missing line `user = new User()`?

Comment: I have field: private User user = new user() :). But my problem is that Visual Studio create tables: User with user data and User View Model and this one is empty.. I do not want this table (UserViewModel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your view do not select the database context. Handle that manually so Visual Studio is not going to automatically change your context class.

When you create a view selecting the ViewModel and the database context, Visual Studio opens the context file and add the DbSet entry for your ViewModel as it doesn't exist. If you don't select it is not going to do anything then you can have control over your file.

---

As a side node, to map properties from your ViewModel to your Model there are tools such as ValueInjecter, it is worth having a look at that.